# How come my app doesn't show up on app store or iTunes searches?

Tags: ios

Three hours ago I received an email regarding my free app that it is "ready for sale". When I go into my iTunes Connect, there is a link to "View in App Store". When I click this link, it appears fine (it shows in iTunes), however when I manually search it in iTunes or app store, nothing appears (finds nothing). Is there a certain wait time for it to appear or did I do something wrong? Thanks.

Comment: probably not indexed yet. wait a few more hours?

Comment: Did you search your name? (developer's name).

Comment: You either wait for few more hours or make sure that you have selected at least a country in the application's setting so it will be available in that country.

Comment: No. It is about me not knowing whether it is supposed to be instant or not.

Comment: in the next 24 hours it will be visible...

Comment: I'm waiting for more than 7 days now. How patient can I be? Did somebody wait so long for publishing on app store?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It takes time for the meta data to propagate through.

There is no "fixed" time for this. As long as it has been set to "Ready for Sale" 
and that you have selected the country for availability as you want, rest assured, 
be patient, it will show.

Congrats, by the way.

Comment: I've been waiting for 7 days. Is this a reasonable time? I mean, should I be  more patient or should I contact the apple support?